# Tensorflow: operator result changes if multiple independent actions on same input are performed

Tags: python, tensorflow

**[Edited below]**

I ran into some unexpected behaviour from tensorflow: the result of an operator changes if I carry out another independent operator first.

I've stripped the project to the minimal code sample below. The output will change if the "*h_chrdP*" line is (un)commented, but that line shouldn't have any effect on the output!

I'm pulling my hair on this one. Can anyone please explain what's wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np   

def ch_redux_layer(input, in_ch, out_ch):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, in_ch, out_ch]))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
    #x = tf.shape([1,1])      # uncomment THIS one for different results, too...
    return tf.nn.relu(conv)


def create_network(graph):
    with graph.as_default():
        state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                    shape=[None, 2, 2, 4],
                    name='state')

        h_chrdP = ch_redux_layer(state, 4, 2)  #(un)comment this line for different results
        h_chrdV = ch_redux_layer(state, 4, 1)

        tf.add_to_collection('state', state)
        tf.add_to_collection('dbg', h_chrdV)


# --------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    state = np.array([[[ 0., 0., -0.2, 0.], [ 0., 0., 0.8, 0.]], [[ 0., 1., 0., 0.], [ 0., 1., 0., 0.]]])

    graph = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
        tf.set_random_seed(66)
        np.random.seed(66)

        create_network(session.graph)
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        n_state = graph.get_collection('state')[0]

        chV = graph.get_collection('dbg')[0]
        print(session.run(chV, feed_dict={n_state: [state]}))
```

**EDIT:**

@Lior, Thanks! I would never have thought of the random seeding but it is completely logical even if the seeds weren't split, because of course the second call generates different random numbers.

It seems that my example was reduced too much; I added in a line now. Can you (or anyone) also explain why the values change if I uncomment the completely ridiculous "*x = tf.shape()*" line in the code, but only if I keep both *ch_redux_layer()* lines?

Comment: It's for the reason I gave in my answer: tf.shape() is an op and it increases the counter (even though it is not random!), therefore the seed of the h_chrdV initializer will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the difference, you need to understand how the random number generator seed works in TensorFlow.

Suppose you set the seed to the value `66`, and then you add two ops (=operations) with randomness, such as `tf.truncated_normal()`. Lets call these ops `op1` and `op2`. Then each op gets its own "private" seed. `op1` will get the seed `(66,1)` while `op2` will get the seed `(66,2)`. As you see, the private seeds are combined from the "global" seed, and from a counter. The counter increases on each addition of an op to the graph.

The result is that when your line is commented, then when you run the line `h_chrdV = ...` it calls `W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, in_ch, out_ch]))`. Since this is the first op added to the graph (Let's suppose it's first), it will have the seed `(66,1)`. But when your line is not commented, then calling `h_chrdV = ...` will be the second time that you add a op (since you added one already by calling `h_chrdP=...`), therefore the seed will be `(66,2)`. And then, when you do `session.run`, you get different random numbers.

You can verify that if you switch the order between the lines `h_chrdP=...` and `h_chrdV=...`, then commenting the former won't change the results.

---

The terminology, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed), is "operation seed" and "graph-level seed" (instead of "global" and "private")

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I reduced the code too much. Please consider the edited version of my question.